# router access not working on Arris DG1670A

Tags: remote-access, router

Not sure if this is for programming only but I will ask anyway. I have an Arris DG1670A router and am trying to setup remote access. I do not have a tab or a section that enables remote access like some routers do. I have tried setting up Virtual Server / Port Forwarding and port triggers which is the closest setting I have seen in my router setting to remote access but when I check if the port I set up is open on canyouseeme.org is shows that the ports are closed.

Can someone provide some direction please.

If I am posting in the wrong place, please advice where to post.

Thank you

Comment: I think [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) is the right site for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable firewall on that model for Port Fordwarding to work.

[Default ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) are TCP/UDP 3389.